# Android System Module does not generate output on build

Tags: c++, android-source

I am experiencing a problem while building android source code(Nougat). I have a system module named `poweroffhandler`, written in C++ and has `Android.mk` file as follow.

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
    #src_files

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
    #libraries

LOCAL_MODULE:= poweroffhandler

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

When i add the file `$(error error_message)` it crashes(with error message "error_message") and stops the whole build.(So the module is included the building sequence) But it does not produce any output after build sequence.

I've tried creating a `.rc` file associated with it as follows.

Added `Android.mk` file ->

```
LOCAL_INIT_RC := PowerOffHandler.rc
```

Created a new file named `PowerOffHandler.rc`

```
service poweroffhandler /system/bin/poweroffhandler
    class core
    user graphics
    group graphics audio
    disabled
    oneshot
```

When i create an `.rc` file it does produce an output at `intermediates` folder but not in the `system/bin` folder.

And the weird part is i can build module with saying from project root: `make poweroffhandler`. Then i have no problem at all, problem is i can't use `build all` scripts for this module(so i can't proceed autonomous integration).

Any help will be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, when you write a system module:

- You need to register your `Android.mk` (for example by saying `include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)` at top level folder)
- You need to register your module (specified by `LOCAL_MODULE:= poweroffhandler`) to `{root}/build/target/product/embedded.mk` by saying `PRODUCT_PACKAGES += poweroffhandler`